# Problem with RecordMyDesktop program

Tags: 12.04, drivers, recordmydesktop

I am trying to record some tutorials using RecordMyDesktop application. The problem is the video becomes jagged and unusable as you can see from the screenshot I have taken while playing a saved video.

I don't know what can be the problem, but I guess it has something to do with my graphics driver. My laptop is using Intel HD 3000 series and I couldn't find any update for it. If you know what might be the problem and how to solve it I will really appreciate it!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks, you just confirmed the same problem I was having. I also have an Intel HD 3000 (Intel DZ68DB Motherboard). With RecordMyDesktop I could not get the video to work because of the same issue. I tried Ubuntu 13.04 (Still in development) and it works perfect. But in 12.04 and 12.10 the only way I could record was using another alternative.

For the Intel HD 3000 Series I recommend Kazam since it is working without any problems and it records very smooth without creating lag in the recorded video or what I am recording at the moment. If you like this idea then feel free to add the PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install kazam`

I choose the unstable branch (Which is not that unstable) since it is more updated. It is running very good on the HD 3000.

Comment: I just found a fix on youtube. I set my resoloution from 1366 to 1360 and the problem is gone! Still think this is a graphic driver problem. Thanks for your answer too!

Comment: Yes you are right. But for me it works 50/50 when I do the resolution thingy. But in 13.04 it is working beautifully! hehe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. reducing the width from 1366 to 1360 is doing the trick, at least for now on 12.04.

Comment: 1360 worked for me as well.

Comment: Changing to 1360 works great. Anyone any explanation for this?